# xsl check if a root node contains any child nodes

Tags: xslt, dotnetnuke

Is there a way to determine if a a root level node contains any child nodes?
I have this code file that builds up a navigation menu for a drop-down menu, but for the root nodes that have no nodes below them I want to apply a different template to them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Home">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="root">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
                <xsl:with-param name="level" select="0"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ul>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="node">
        <xsl:param name="level" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$level=0">
                <li>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">
                        <xsl:if test="@breadcrumb = 1">active</xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="node">
                            <xsl:text>&#32;dropdown</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>


                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@enabled = 1">
                           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                                    <xsl:if test="node">
                                        <xsl:text>dropdown-toggle</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:if test="node">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="data-toggle">dropdown</xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                                <xsl:if test="node">
                                    <b class="caret"></b>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </a>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>

                            <xsl:value-of select="@text" />

                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:if test="node">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
                                <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </ul>
                    </xsl:if>
                </li>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <li>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">
                        <xsl:if test="@breadcrumb = 1">active</xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="node">
                            <xsl:text>&#32;dropdown</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@enabled = 1">
                            <a href="{@url}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                            </a>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </li>
                <xsl:if test="node">
                    <!-- no extra level in default bootstrap -->
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What about the function count, and can you post a minimal xml?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear. If the **root node** does not have any child nodes, then the XML document is empty. Perhaps you meant the **root element**; there will be exactly one element like that and it's easy to see if it has any child nodes by using:

```
test="/*/node()"
```

in an `xsl:if` or `xsl:when` instruction.

---

Alternatively, you could use two templates - one matching a root element with child nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="/*[node()]">
```

and one for the other case:

```
<xsl:template match="/*[not(node())]">
```

Comment: I suspect that by "root level node" the OP means "elements named root".

Comment: @MichaelKay The use of the word "level" conflicts with such interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XSLT-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="/*[count(descendant::*) = 0]">
      No siblings
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*[count(descendant::*) > 0]">
      Has siblings
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With an input XML file with one or more siblings of the root element like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <a />
</root>
```

it will output "Has siblings".

And with an input file with an empty root tag like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
</root>
```

it will output "No siblings".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, try adding the template rule

```
<xsl:template match="root[not(*)]"/>
```